# Remove unwanted fields from WP API response

Tags: rest-api, api, wp-api, http-api

I am making a mobile app that links to a Wordpress site. There are a lot of unwanted data from the API response and it would be great if I could remove it. 
How could I do that without touching the PHP (I know nothing of it)? I am using React Native in the front end.

Is there a good plugin or query params in the URL to solve this?

Comment: why do you need to do that?

Comment: I am getting a huge response back in the front end. I just need a few fields for eg. id, topic etc but not content, date and so on. For performance.

Comment: This is answered here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45027789/remove-links-object-from-wp-rest-api-response-by-filter-or-hook#:~:text=Unfortunately%2C%20you%20cannot%20remove%20it%2C%20it's%20protected.&text=The%20rest_prepare_post%20is%20the%20right,remove%20things%20to%20it%20directly.